# Integer Overflow irvine32

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

i wrote a code for this c++ expression in assembly language using 32 bit unsigned operands

If (val2 ==0) then

{val2 = 1}

val1 = (val3 / val2) * (val1 + val3)

but i got error "overflow Integer"
the error is at `div val2` when i enter the val1 =  600, val2= 0, val3= 1000 any higher number won't work just the smaller number... how to correct this?

[https://i.imgur.com/ivcRkVI.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKEUK.png)

```
    INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
val1 BYTE ?
val2 BYTE ?
val3 BYTE ?
prompt BYTE "Please enter 3 numbers: ",0
out1 BYTE "val1 = (val3 / val2) * (val1 + val3) = ",0
.code
main PROC  
   ;;CLEAR ALL REGISTERS
   xor eax,eax
   xor ebx,ebx
   xor ecx,ecx
   xor edx,edx
   ;;DISPLAY PROMPT
   mov edx,offset prompt
   call writestring
   ;;NEWLINW
   mov al,0ah
   call writechar
   ;;READ VAL1 AND STORE
   call readint
   mov val1,al
   ;;READ VAL2 AND CHECK AND STORE
   call readint
   cmp al,0   ;;CHECK IF 0
   jnz skip
   mov val2,1   ;;IF 0, MAKE VAL1 AS 1
   jmp readnext
skip:
   mov val2,al   ;;ELSE STORE SAME VALUE
readnext:
   ;;READ VAL3 AND STORE
   call readint
   mov val3,al
   div val2   ;;CALCULATE VAL3/VAL2
   mov bl,al   ;;SAVE IN BL
   mov al,val3  
   add al,val1   ;;ADD VAL3+VAL1
   mul bl       ;;(VAL3/VAL2)*(VAL3+VAL1)
   ;;DISPLAY MESSAGE
   mov edx,offset out1
   call writestring
   ;;DISPLAY ANSWER
   call writedec
   ;;DUMP REGISTERS
   call dumpregs
call waitmsg       ;;WAIT FOR A KEY PRESS
INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Answer (score 1):

You are *using 32 bit unsigned operands* but your variables `val1 BYTE ?` etc are declared as 8bit only, number above 255 will not fit in them. 32bit binary number obtained from `readint` should be stored with
`mov val1,eax` and not `mov val1,al`.

It is pointless to `;;CLEAR ALL REGISTERS` before you move anything to them but be sure to clear EDX before `div val2   ;;CALCULATE VAL3/VAL2` because the instruction [DIV](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div) expects its dividend in 64bit register pair EDX:EAX.

Comment: I got your point but how I can make the division in 64bit
because i tried but i think i did it wrong

Comment: @MohamadAlkousi  Actualy it is 32bit division. The bitness of division is controled  by the divisor width, which is 32 if you declare your variable `val2` as DWORD.    
Intel says:  
Unsigned divide EDX:EAX by r/m32, with result stored in EAX ← Quotient, EDX ← Remainder.